# How to toggle commenting and uncommeting code in IDEA?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Is there a way to comment/uncomment a block of selected text in IDEA?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, highlight the block and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.  To uncomment, just repeat.

Comment: repeating adds another comment block.

Answer (score 4):

with <kbd>Shift</kbd> this makes for block style comments `/**/`, without it for line style comments <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> -> `\\` (tested with IDEA 10U)

Comment: how to uncomment after commenting , with both block and line style?

Comment: go to the commented place in code and do the same @JunaidShirwani - this will toggle it back. Shift-Crtl-/ will uncomment from within block style comments and Ctrl-/ will do that from within line style

Comment: its not, its adding another comment over the already commented block. I am using intellij

Comment: if you tested line comments (Ctrl-Slash, also in top meny -> Code -> Comment with Line Comment) @JunaidShirwani then please pay attention that after this cursor goes down one line, so you need to additionally move cursor back to the commented line in order to do uncomment

Comment: i first comment with Ctrl+Shift+slash . after that i selected the whole commented block and again pressed Ctrl+Shift+slash which added another comment block over the already commented block. Am i missing something?

Comment: that's very strange @JunaidShirwani - I just repeated your actions step by step and pressing Ctrl+Shift+slash second time uncommented the block (I'm on Ultimate 2016.3 now if that matters). You know one thing I noticed while experimenting today is key presses sometimes didn't work as I expected - they worked well in scenario you described but still. To exclude the chance of something weird with keyboard you can try repeating this using menu instead of keypresses (top menu -> Code -> Comment with Block Comment instead of Ctrl+Shift+slash)

Comment: yes it is working with top menu options but not with key shortcut . That is quite strange . I have the same version of intellij sa yours but this is quite strange . If its something to do with some settings in intellij , then do help me out .

Comment: Yes it does not work as shortcut on  2016.3.4
I think is one of the basic things that is needed :-(

Answer (score 1):

Jetbrains provides a [printable reference card](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) with the default set of Windows *and* Mac key bindings.

For the benefit of others who might stumble across this question & answers...  In addition to the windows key binding provided in other answers, there is also a keystroke for toggling a comment bock in IntelliJ IDEA on the Mac.

**Line Comment**

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

**Block Comment**

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> doesn't work under Mac with Spanish keyboard layout, because this shortcut it's bind to the main character on the key, which in this case is <kbd>7</kbd>, not <kbd>/</kbd>.

For someone else having the same issue, pressing the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> in Windows) is the shorcut for single-line comment while <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> works for multi-line comments.

Comment: In my case (I'm using the latest Mac OS 10.5 keymap), this does not work, because pressing `Cmd`+ `-` activates the Collapse action, so at this moment I don't know how I solved it in other laptops...

Comment: I have OSX El Capitan version 10.11.6 with Spanish keyboard

Comment: I was talking about the Keymap that I'm using in IntelliJ. I think that this combination works for you if you change your Keyboard layout to US/EN keyboard, otherwise it will not work (at least not for me) I had to remove the shortcut attached to the Expand/Collapse code block and assign it to `Cmd`+ `Shift`+`-` / `Cmd`+`-` /

Comment: For the 3rd time, Spanish keyboard... maybe different Intellij versions than yours (my case Intellij IDEA 15.0.6) since my IDE uses also the `Mac OS X 10.5 +` keyboard. This worked for me without changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

use this Simbol 
/*
write any thing
*/

For windows 
  Ctrl + Shift + /
For mac
 Cmd+Shift+-

Answer (score 0):

If the `Cmd`+`Shift`+`/` doesn't work for you (often the case with spanish / german and other keyboards) and you don't want to set it to US/EN keyboard, then use:

`Cmd`+`Alt`+`s` to open the IntelliJ-settings -> select `Keymap` and search for "Comment with Line Comment" or "Comment with Block Comment". Then rightclick on it and select "add Keyboard Shortcut" and set your own shortcut, for example: `Cmd`+`Shift`+`NumPad /`

Answer (score 0):

This functionality also seems to not work in the latest version(s) for file types that you add to IDEA. For example, it works fine for .java files, but not for other file types that I've configured.

Edit: Here's a thread on the Jetbrains site explaining this. Apparently it needs a custom plug-in for each file extension:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000118344-Comment-with-Line-Comment-does-not-work